# Battery draining extremely quickly Galaxy S7

Tags: battery-life, samsung-galaxy-s7, overheating

My phones battery was draining extremely quickly a few moments ago, around 1% per 2 seconds. It's been doing this fairly often but when I go to **device management and clean everything** it usually stops draining.

This time though, the battery kept on being chugged and I couldn't find any explanation as to why it would get drained like that, everything was asleep or off. Even after **turning off and on my device**, the battery kept going down and the phone kept getting hotter and hotter.

Would any one know what else I could do? I feel as though I tried everything possible.

(in case this happens again since it randomly decided to stop chugging.)

Thanks,

to note:

- Device software is up to date.
- Device is 1 1/2 years old.

Comment: Not to bash Galaxies but the battery life was terrible after a year and did exactly what you described on future updates when I owned one.  From my understanding the updates are what kill the battery life, but I have no proof only me guessing.  You can try a factor reset but that is about it.

Comment: @William well see, the problem isnt the battery or anything because on average, my battery lasts a full day of use, but for that moment, the battery was being drained exceptionally quickly which I can only imagine was because of a background application and not simply the software or battery.

Comment: Have you already checked with our [battery-life tag-wiki](/tags/battery-life/info) and the hints pointed from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has being a common problem with S6 due to update to marshmallow, I believe this should also work for your S7.

Wipe your phone **cache** or **system partition** by following the steps below;

> Go to **Settings**
>
> **Storage and USB**
>
> **Cached Data**
>
> **OK**. This should wipe your system partition.

Or you can also do the same thing from recovery mode by following the steps bellow:

> - Turn off your Galaxy S7.
> - Press and hold Power
> - When ‘Samsung Galaxy S7’ appears, immediately release the Power key and then press and hold the Volume Down button to access **Fastboot**
> - Use the volume buttons to highlight Recovery and press Power to confirm.
> - If you see the Android robot, press Power, then Volume up briefly to access Recovery.
> - Scroll down to Wipe cache partition and hit Power to confirm.
> - Scroll down to Yes and hit Power to confirm.
> - Reboot

If the problem persists, you can also clear the app cache for your device and the last resort is to do a full backup and perform a factory reset. Wiping your device and restoring your apps and data is one of the simplest and best ways to avoid any weirdness battery drain and general system performance issues.

Comment: That seems like something that should work, if this issue happens again, I'll attempt this after and hopefully I never get the issue again. It's just a little strange that it occurs randomly and just starts draining my battery.

But if it persists, I'll be sure to try this, thanks!

Comment: Has it answered your question?

Comment: I haven't gotten the chance to try it out, but I guess I could accept it despite that since it seems like the best possible answer.